# How can i disable a button(say button1) when clicking anothor button(say button2)?

Tags: javascript, odoo-9, odoo-10

How can i disable a button(say button1) when clicking anothor button(say button2)  in header in odoo10 using javascript??

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the help section on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
        <button class="button buttonOne">Button One</button>
        <button class="button buttonTwo">Button Two</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
            var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');

            for (var i = 0; btns.length > i; i++) {
                btns[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
                    disableElements(evt.target);
                });
            }

            function disableElements(activeEl) {
                var els = document.querySelectorAll('button');
                var target = activeEl;

                for (var i = 0; els.length > i; i++) {
                    if (els[i] !== target) {
                        els[i].setAttribute('disabled', true);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: #Darren_Sweeney , Thank you so much for your answer. I gave these two buttons in the xml file and put js code in js file. I tried to get the length of the variable btn in an alert box, but it shows 0. So, how could i solve this problem? I'm using odoo 10 framework. Does these js syntax or code suitable for odoo10 formats??

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

1. Define a field `flag=True` in  `*.py` and `*.xml`.
2. Define function `set_flag` in `*.py`.
3. In `set_flag` set `flag` value `False`.
4. In `xml`, give a condition to invisible the button.

Example:

**Py**

```
flag = fields.Boolean('flag', default=True)

@api.multi
def set_flag(self):
    self.flag=False
```

***.xml**

```
 <button class="button buttonOne" name="set_falg"/>
 <button class="button buttonTwo" attrs="{'invisible':[('flag','=',False)]}"/>
 <field name="flag" invisble="1"/>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: #KbiR, Thank you so much for your answer. It works. But my actual need is that I want to disable/hide a button when click on another button using javascript.. I'm new to odoo 10. Please help me If you know the solution. And 1 more question, How can I access a form content in xml file in js file??

Answer (score 0):

I'll simply keep a switch field(Boolean) whose values changed to False when button 2 is clicked. Now I can just set an attribute on button 1 that makes it readonly if the value of switch is False.

Here is the code:

**Python**

```
switch= fields.Boolean(default=True)

def change_status(self):
    self.switch= False
```

**XML**

```
 <field name="switch" invisible="1"/>
 <button string='Button1' attrs="{'readonly':[('switch','=',False)]}">Button One</button>
 <button string='Button2' name="change_status">Button Two</button>
```

Here, **name="change_status"** is a link to the python function which changes the status of the switch.

**P.S: To make it work properly, add the invisible field ('switch' here) before using its values in attribute to set the readonly status.**